# Python regex, how to search for multiple strings?

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to python and am trying to figure out python regex to find any strings that match -. For example, `'type1-001'` and `'type2-001'` should be  a match, but `'type3-asdf001'` shouldn't be a match. I would like to be able to match with a regex like `[type1|type2|type3]-\d+` to find any strings that start with `type1`, `type2`, or `type3` and then are appended with `'-'` and digits. Also, it would be cool to know how to search for any upper case text appended with '-' and digits.

Here's what I think should work, but I can't seem to get it right...

```
pref_num = re.compile(r'[type1|type2]-\d+')
```

Comment: Just FYI here, but a regex that searches for multiple strings is kind of redundant, as the whole point of a regex is to search for multiple strings. If you were only searching for one string, you could test for membership with `in`, and the match would simply be the string itself.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Not really. I can give you regexes that search for a single static string but includes multiple conditions that are not possible using a simple text search.

Comment: @poke nailed it, my example is simplified, but i need to search for single static strings that include multiple conditions that aren't possible with simple text search (without keeping/updating a list of all of those strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` will match any of the set of characters appearing between the brackets. To group regexes you need to use `()`. So, I think your regex should be something like:

```
pref_num = re.compile(r'(type1|type2)-\d+')
```

As to how to search any uppercase text appended with `-` and digits, I would suggest:

```
[A-Z]+-\d+
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers both of my questions. Perfect. Also, the () vs [] was key to matching the group regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the digit after "type" to be variable then you should put only those in the square brackets like so:

```
re.compile(r'type[1|2]-\d+')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern

```
'type[1-3]-[0-9]{3}'
```

Demo

```
>>> import re
>>> p = 'type[1-3]-[0-9]{3}'
>>> s = 'type2-005 with some text type1-101 and then type1-asdf001'
>>> re.findall(p, s)
['type2-005', 'type1-101']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pref_num = re.compile(r'(type1|type2|type3)-\d+')

m = pref_num.search('type1-000')
if m != None: print(m.string)

m = pref_num.search('type2-000')
if m != None: print(m.string)

m = pref_num.search('type3-abc000')
if m != None: print(m.string)
```